# Why is .075 * 100 coming out as 7.499999999999996 in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning Javascript at the moment and the particular lesson that I'm on right now is showing how to turn 1.075 into 7.5% for display purposes.

the math looks as follows:

(1.075 - 1) * 100

and this is displaying in the results as 7.499999999999996.  Why in the world is it calculating like this in Javascript?  Every calculator that I used to do the exact same math came up as 7.5, as it should.  I didn't even need a calculator to realize something was odd, but I wanted to run the same numbers on as many calculators as I could just to reassure myself.  I'm actually shocked that the guy doing the tutorials didn't say a single thing about that, other than how to fix it to display only 2 decimal places, because this just seems so odd.  So what be going on?  I'm crazy curious about what's going on here.

Thanks!

I want to apologize to everyone that was obviously very upset by my asking a duplicate question, and decided to downvote me for it.  I would have been just as well searching for an answer, only I don't even know how I could have began to query for such a question.

To the people that answered, and linked me to another article answering my question; thank you very much, and I apologize for the duplicate :)

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: We shouldn't dump downvotes on duplicate questions.  See [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62819/should-we-downvote-duplicates).

Comment: Try representing `.075` in binary and see how it goes.  Also note that `7.499999999999996` is `7.5`, but it is not `7.500000000000000`.

Comment: 1075/1000 is periodic number in binary (1.000 1001 1001 1001 ...) just like 1/3 is a periodic number in decimal (0.3333...). As such, it cannot be represented exactly using floating point numbers.

Comment: I appreciate your comment, SuperScript.  It indeed is not right.  I'm not even sure how I could begin to know how to search for an answer to this question. And I appreciate everyone else's comments explaining this as well :)

Comment: @SuperScript No they shouldn't. I didn't downvote, but it doesn't surprise me too much that others did. Not because it's a duplicate, but because the question doesn't show a great deal of research effort, given that there are dozens of other questions just like this on SO and a large number of off-site resources discussing this topic. That said, if the tutorial OP is reading didn't make *any* mention of this, then OP should probably look for a better tutorial site.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I'm sorry, but how can one successfully find an answer if they are not sure what questions to ask?  I could easily enough put the question into words that another Human Being could understand, but I didn't even know where to BEGIN to be able to put the question in a search string that would return relative results.  That being said, this tutorial could be better, but it is only one of many tutorials that I will be using and it is teaching me.  The lack of detail forces me to pause the video and examine the code to try to fill in the gaps.   In a way, I think that's helpful.

Comment: @p.s.w.g also, the guy did explain how to display it with exactly 2 decimal places.  I mentioned that in the OP though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some decimal numbers cannot be accurately stored as floating point numbers since they are periodic in binary. 1075/1000 is such a number.

http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: right... storing floating point decimal numbers in binary....